# How do I implement Angular's "banana in a box" two-way binding with Custom Elements?

Tags: angular, custom-element

I'm trying to build a custom element that will be consumed by an Angular app. The custom element will take a prop and potentially manipulate it.

My understanding was that I could use the "banana in a box" to handle this binding, aka `<custom-element [(foo)]="bar">` gets converted to `<custom-element [foo]="bar" (fooChange)="bar = newBar">`, or the like.

My Angular template:

```
<an-el [(clicked)]="isClicked"></an-el>
<p>Did you click a button? {{ isClicked }}</p>
```

My custom element dispatches an event:

`this.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent('clickedChange', { bubbles: true, detail: true }));`

But it appears to bind the entire CustomEvent to `isClicked`:

```
Did you click a button? [object CustomEvent]
```

What am I doing wrong?

Here's my app (run in Chrome): https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nlguf4

Comment: @JBNizet AFAIK we can handle custom events via `(output)` syntax. But we will get `CustomEvent` as `$event` parameter

Comment: Yeah, I think you could rewrite this to `<an-el [clicked]="isClicked" (clickedChange)="isClicked = $event.detail">` to make it work. But it's unfortunate that there's a difference with how the "banana in a box" approach works depending on if you're using an `@Output` or if it's a CustomEvent; was hoping to unify them.

Comment: I'm being explicit about it here: https://codesandbox.io/s/stripe-elements-web-component-angular-0mgh4?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&module=%2Fsrc%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts&theme=dark

Answer (score 0):

I would replace `isClicked` declaration with:

```
private _isClicked = false;

public get isClicked() {
    return this._isClicked;
  }
public set isClicked(val: CustomEvent | boolean) {
    this._isClicked = typeof val === "boolean" ? val : val["detail"];
  }
```