# return isTrusted false

Tags: events, two-way-binding, stenciljs

I'm writing my first web component with Stencil.
It's a pills component published here : https://github.com/reservoir-dogs/rp-pills

The component code's :

```
import { Component, Prop, Watch, Event, EventEmitter } from '@stencil/core';

@Component({
  tag: 'rp-pills',
  styleUrl: 'rp-pills.scss',
  shadow: false
})
export class RpPills {

  @Prop() items: any[] = [];
  @Prop() displayProperty: string;
  @Prop({ mutable: true }) value: any;
  @Prop() class: string;
  @Prop() theme: string = 'default';
  @Prop() emptyMessage: string = 'No item';
  classes: string;

  @Event() valueChange: EventEmitter;

  onClick(item: any) {
    this.value = item;
    this.valueChange.emit(this.value);
  }

  @Watch('class')
  @Watch('theme')
  watchHandler() {
    this.classes = `nav nav-pills ${this.theme} ${this.class}`;
  }

  render() {
    if (this.items.length > 0)
      return (
        <ul class={this.classes}>
          {this.items.map((item) =>
            <li onClick={() => this.onClick(item)} class={this.value === item ? 'active' : ''} >
              <a>{item[this.displayProperty]}</a>
            </li>)}
        </ul>
      );
    else
      return (
        <ul class={this.classes}>
          <li class="empty">
            <a>{this.emptyMessage}</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      );
  }
}
```

This test work fine :

```
it('should work with a list of items and selected item', async () => {
  const cmp = new RpPills();
  cmp.valueChange = {
    emit: () => { }
  };
  const spy = jest.spyOn(cmp.valueChange, 'emit');
  cmp.onClick({name:'Coucou'});
  expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith({ name: 'Coucou' });
});
```

But my HTML sample and an integration in Ionic App does not work and return the following message : {"isTrusted":false}

HTML sample :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=5.0">
  <title>Stencil Component Starter</title>
  <script src="/build/rppills.js"></script>
</head>
<style>
  .orange .active a {
    background-color: #ff0000;
  }

  .orange a {
    background-color: #ff6a00;
  }

  div {
    float: left;
    clear: both;
  }
</style>
<body>

  <div>
    <rp-pills display-property="name" class="nav-pills-bordered" theme="orange">
    </rp-pills>
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <rp-pills display-property="name" class="nav-justified">
    </rp-pills>
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <rp-pills display-property="name" class="nav-pills-bordered nav-justified">
    </rp-pills>
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <rp-pills class="nav-pills-bordered">
    </rp-pills>
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <rp-pills empty-message="Aucun message" class="nav-pills-bordered">
    </rp-pills>
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <div>
    <rp-pills>
    </rp-pills>
    <span></span>
  </div>

  <script>
    var cmps = document.querySelectorAll('rp-pills');
    for (var i = 0; i < cmps.length; i++) {
      var cmp = cmps[i];
      if (cmp.attributes.length > 0 && cmp.attributes[0].name == 'display-property') {
        cmp.value = { 'name': 'Coucou' };
        cmp.items = [cmp.value, { 'name': 'Comment ca va ?' }, { 'name': 'Au revoir' }];
        cmp.addEventListener('valueChange', (event) => { alert(JSON.stringify(event)); });
      }
    }
    setInterval(() => {
      var cmps = document.querySelectorAll('rp-pills');
      var spans = document.querySelectorAll('span');
      for (var i = 0; i < cmps.length; i++) {
        if (cmps[i].value != undefined)
          spans[i].innerText = cmps[i].value.name;
      }
    }, 1000);
  </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

2 errors

I tried to do that :

```
<rp-pills [items]="jeux" [(value)]="partie.jeu"></rp-pills>
```

The event of my Stencil component's :

1. is not compliant with angular two-way binding
2. contain a property 'detail' where there is my value

Use in Ionic App

HTML code

```
<rp-pills [items]="jeux" [value]="partie.jeu" (valueChange)="jeuChange($event.detail)"></rp-pills>
```

TypeScript code

```
jeuChange(jeu: Jeu) {
  this.partie.jeu = jeu;
}
```

Comment: You can't do two-way binding this way with custom elements. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48526067/how-do-i-implement-angulars-banana-in-a-box-two-way-binding-with-custom-eleme